# Automatize using bash downloading deb files and dependencies and later extracting them to a unique folder and compress it to use in a live filesystem

Tags: bash, apt, dpkg, deb

I am developing a Live filesystem and need to be able to download deb files with its dependencies which I manually do using:

```
apt download $(apt-cache depends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests \
--no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances \
--no-pre-depends ${PACKAGES} | grep "^\w")
```

After that, I need to extract all data.tar.gz from required deb packages combined to one unique folder (the mv command is not very useful in merging folders) which I manually do using both /usr/bin/ar x or dpkg-deb later combined with tar to extract all files from data.tar.gz from $DEB

Is there a bash way to automatize the whole process disregard the number of downloaded $DEB files?
Thank you.